# StatefulKnowledgeSession saturates the memory

Tags: drools

I use Drools 7.0 to evaluate promotions in the shopping cart of my e-commerce website. I have 2300 promotions/rules.

I can see that during the execution of *StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules()* that *StatefulKnowledgeSession* consumes too much memory (around 500MB). From heap dump analysis, I can see it is mostly due to *BetaMemory* objects that are created (around 260K).

The memory is cleaned after a GC but it causes performance issue due to too frequent GC.

I guess it may come from the complexity of my rules but I have not been able to point of the issue and I have may different rule types.

Do you have tips to share so I can troubleshoot my problem and understand why the evaluation of the network creates so many *BetaMemory* objects.